# Autoload tFPDF class with composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, fpdf

I want to use the [tFPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php) class and load it with composer-autoload. Since I could not find an official tFPDF composer repo, I simply downloaded the zip file and extracted it in the folder `vendor/tfpdf`.

Next I added the psr-4 to the `composer.json` file:

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "tFPDF\\": "vendor/tFPDF"
        },
```

I also added in the `tfpdf.php` the namespace

```
<?php
namespace tFPDF;

define('tFPDF_VERSION','1.25');

class tFPDF
{
```

Finally I produced a new autoload file:

> composer dump-autoload

When I now try to create a PDF like this:

```
$pdf = new \tFPDF\tfpdf();
$pdf->AddPage();

// Add a Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
```

Then the last line will rise an error:

> Cannot access private property tFPDF\TTFontFile::$charWidths

[image]

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: What changes are you do for `TTFontFile` class? (loaded in line 509)

Comment: Are you test: https://github.com/rev42/tfpdf ?

Comment: @bato3 I have not done any changes to `TTFontFile`. All I did was adding the namespace tag in the `tfpdf.php` file, thats it. https://github.com/rev42/tfpdf is depriciated and recommends to use https://github.com/DocnetUK/tfpdf. However the latter one is using different function names then the original so it breaks with almost all existing scripts for `fpdf` (see issue https://github.com/DocnetUK/tfpdf/issues/26).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now a package https://github.com/Setasign/tfpdf (released in September 2018, a couple of month after the question was asked here)

Install with composer like this:

```
composer require setasign/tfpdf
```

you can either use it like this:

```
namespace your\namespace;

class Document extends \tFPDF
```

or like this:

```
$pdf = new \tFPDF();
```